# What is the meaning of replan:true, truncated:command?

Tags: mongodb

This a command I saw in mongod.log while there are CPU spikes on our VM. What is the meaning of replan:true? And the replanReason: cached plan was less efficient than expected......

[image]

As seen from the image above, what does this truncated section mean? I could not find it on mongodb doc

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/cloud-manager/performance-advisor/slow-query-threshold/

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple questions being asked in this question, but the answers to all of them can be found in the documentation.

For replanning, the corresponding entries mentioned in [the profiler documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-profiler/#mongodb-data-system.profile.replanned) are relevant:

> **`system.profile.replanned`**
>
> A boolean that indicates whether the query system evicted a cached plan and re-evaluated all candidate plans.
>
> Only present when value is `true`.
>
> **`system.profile.replanReason`**
>
> *New in version 4.4.*
>
> A string that indicates the specific reason a cached plan was evicted.
>
> Only present when value for `replanned` is `true`.

As for truncation, it indicates that the log entry was too long to capture in its entirety. This is usually caused by the client sending a large request, which in your case looks like a large `$in` list. [Here is a section about it in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/#truncation):

> Any *attributes* that exceed the maximum size defined with `maxLogSizeKB` (default: 10 KB) are truncated. Truncated attributes omit log data beyond the configured limit, but retain the JSON formatting of the entry to ensure that the entry remains parsable.

The documentation further goes on to give more information with an example.